# Can I steam-bend a piece of wood with a free-floating end?

Tags: steam-bending

I've been working on creating a wooden hockey stick. The blade of the hockey stick needs a slight curve and bend to it.

I have a small steam box set up and have created a vice with different-length teeth in it. After steaming the wood, I place it in the vice, close the teeth, and let it sit for a day or two. The curve created  by the teeth in the vice is much more exaggerated than I need, and when I remove it from the vice, the blade springs back a bit.  However, over time, the blade continues to straighten. After a week or so, it's almost to it's original straightness.

Most steam-bending applications that I've seen have both ends of the bent wood fixed so even though the wood wants to spring back, it can't.

Is it possible to steam-bend a piece of wood to have it remain bent without fixing both ends of the piece? Will all wood eventually straighten over time if left alone?

Comment: Make a 2-handled hockey stick?  :)

Answer (score 8):

One way to combat this is to glue multiple layers that have been steamed over a form. Essentially, you'll be making a custom piece of curved plywood. The internal stresses will keep the workpiece from deforming back to its original shape.

Tage Frid has an excellent book on [shaping, veneering, and finishing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0918804116) that covers this topic in depth.

(I have no association with Tage Frid and his literature, other than owning several of his books.)